# PHP with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I've looked around different questions relating this topic, but none have what I need. I seems simple, but it's still not working. Logically I thought it would work. I have a login form, where I query a select for the user and the password, after that I check if the user and the pw are empty, if not I check if it's in the data base. If it's in the data base redirect somewhere else. Here's the thing, when I load the page, I don't see the txtBox or anything. If I delete the php chunk, everything works fine. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

What I wrote:

```
<html>

<head>

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "longInStyle.css">

<script>

    function fieldValidation()
    {
        if( document.getElementById("username").value == "" || document.getElementById("username").value == " " ) 
            { 
                alert("The username field is empty. Please, enter a username");   

                document.getElementById('username').focus();              

                return false;            
            } 

        else if(document.getElementById("password").value == "" || document.getElementById("password").value == " " )
            {                
                alert("The password field is empty. Please, enter a password");   

                document.getElementById('password').focus();                  

                return false; 
            }

        else
        {
              <?php

                include 'config.php';

                $usr = $_POST["username"];

                $pass = $_POST["password"];

                $usrCount = 0;

                $passCount = 0;


                $SQLUsr = " SELECT USERNAME FROM Users WHERE USERNAME = '$usr' ";

                $result = mysql_query($SQLUsr);

                $SQLPass = " SELECT PASSWORD FROM Users WHERE PASSWORD = '$pass' ";

                $result2 = mysql_query($SQLPass); 

                $usrCount = mysql_num_rows($result);

                $passCount = mysql_num_rows($result2);


                    if($result == 1)
                    {
                        $SQLLvl = " SELECT USERLEVEL FROM Users WHERE USERNAME = '$usr' ";

                        $result3 = mysql_query($SQLLvl);

                        if($result2 == 1)
                        {
                            if($result3 == "Super")
                            {
                                header("location:superUserMain.html");
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                header("location:editMain.html");       
                            }

                            mysql_close($db_handle);                             
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            <script>

                                alert("The wrong password.");   

                                document.getElementById('password').focus();

                            </script>
                        }

                    } 

                    else
                    {
                        <script>

                              alert("The wrong username.");   

                             document.getElementById('username').focus(); 

                        </script>
                    }

                ?>  

            return true;
        }
    }

</script>   

</head>

<body>

    <form method = "post" onsubmit = " return fieldValidation()">

        <div>

            <div>

                Username

            </div>

            <input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username">

        </div>

        <div>

        <div>

            Password

        </div>

        <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password">       

        </div>        

        <div>

            <input type="submit" id = "logIngBtn" name = "logInBtn" value = "Login">           


        </div>           

    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

I saved it as a php file.

config.php has the data base credentials. Username, password and everything else to access it.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between client-side and server-side and the HTTP request cycle. *Hugely* important in web development.

Comment: In addition to what @JohnConde said you also need to quit using mysql_ functions (it is being deprecated) and move to mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: In addition to what the other two said, your code formatting is appalling - how do you expect anyone to read that?

Comment: @JayBlanchard why should I use mysqli_ or POD. Every example I saw used what I did.

Comment: Because mysql_ is deprecated and will be removed from PHP before much longer. There are thousands of examples out there using it because it has been around a long time, but that doesn't mean that it is now correct to use it.

Comment: @TheBlueDog I'm practicing. I just finished high school and I want to be ready for college. I learned on my own so I really didn't know I was formatting the wrong way. I'm just doing what my books says.

Comment: @JohnConde I'll see what I can find on client-side, server-side and HTTP request cycle. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To expand on John Condes comment:

You're using JavaScript to control whether PHP code will be executed. This isn't possible (at least not in the way you're trying to do it). PHP code runs on the server, before anything is sent to the client (the users browser). JavaScript (in your context, at least) only runs in the client (the users browser). By the time your JS decides whether the PHP should run, it's too late. The browser has no understanding of the PHP code you're giving it.

I'd suggest starting with a good tutorial on how to build an AJAX login form with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: I agree it's not the simplest place to start, but it's the closest to what he's trying to achieve. I think.

Comment: I understand now. So that's why it wasn't working. I'll read up on ajax. Thanks

Comment: why do I have -4? Am I suppose to be really good a programming to ask questions? I'm only trying to improve my skills

Comment: If a comment is seen as not useful to the community, it'll generally be downvoted. This link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Don't take the downvotes as a reflection of yourself or your skills. It's an indicator of the quality of the question. Since your question centered around a lack of understanding of the basics of these technologies, you're getting downvoted. Don't sweat it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the haters man...

To help you out though it might be a idea to do what John Conde and mchandleraz said. But to be fair if you are new to this then I think you are doing really well... I still use procedural code as I'm still learning and none of my code is live.

Jay Blanchard is right though mysql_ functions and procedural code is being deprecated and can pose a massive security risk on a live site as someone could potentailly hack your database and steal or your customers information for example. BTW don't take comments on here to heart, programmers tend to be straight talking people by nature.. so don't be surprised if you do something wrong to get slammed for it!

In regards to your question though there are a ton of youtube videos that you can follow on this kind of stuff... failing that buy a book.

Hope you resolve your issue.

Happy coding! :)